# Maximum allowed number in input[text]

Tags: html, angular

Is it possible to set maximum allowed number value in input[text] like we can do it in input[number] to validate it in Angular form??

Thank you

Comment: what about `maxlength` attribute?

Comment: I need max value as 10, with maxlength="1" it can be 9 or 99 with maxlength="2"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a reactive form? If yes just declare the max/min value in form-control.

```
new FormControl("", [Validators.max(100), Validators.min(0)])
```

Comment: I use template driven form

Comment: And you want to limit maximum number value or the digit? @AndriiBlinov

Comment: I need to set maximum digit as 10

Answer (score 0):

You can always set maxlength on input text in angular.

```
<input name="firstName" ngModel maxlength="25">
```

Comment: I need maximum digit as 10

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do this

```
<input aria-label="text input " type="text" pattern="^[-+]?([0-9](\.[0-9]+)?|[0-4][0-9](\.[0-9]+)?|50(\.[0]+)?)$">
```

You can use Regex patterns

Here I have included a pattern which takes values from -50 to +50

or add this to block other text

```
 oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/regex strrings or non numbers/g, '').replace(/regex for numbers greater that upper limit/g, '$1')"
```

Comment: I'm not good at regexp. How can set min value = 0 and max value = 10 with this pattern?

Comment: actually min value is not important, just need max value as 10

Comment: ^[-+]?([0-9](\.[0-9]+)?|10(\.[0]+)?)$   this will be for -10 to 10

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a template driven form, create a directive to apply the min/max validators on your input...

```
@Directive({
  selector: `[appNumberMax][formControlName],
             [appNumberMax][formControl],
             [appNumberMax][ngModel]`,
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: NumberMaxDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class NumberMaxDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('appNumberMax') max: string;
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return Validators.max(+this.max)(control);
  }
}
```

```
<input type="text" ngModel name="someNumber" appNumberMax="99">
```